# Liferay 7 JournalArticleDisplay error on templatehandler

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, liferay, liferay-7

I'm currently on a liferay 7.1 version.

I'm getting a journal article (web content in BO). I want to get the journal article display associated.

In liferay 6.2, I used :

```
JournalArticleDisplay journalDisplay = JournalContentUtil.getDisplay(journalArticle.getGroupId(), journalArticle.getArticleId(), "", locale.getLanguage(), themeDisplay);
```

Now, in liferay 7.1, it doesn't work and I used :

```
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticleDisplay(journalArticle.getGroupId(), journalArticle.getArticleId(), "", locale.getLanguage(), themeDisplay);
```

But this code return me a NullPointerException in JournalUtil.transform in the following line :

```
TemplateHandler templateHandler = TemplateHandlerRegistryUtil.getTemplateHandler(JournalArticle.class.getName());
```

What can i do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can start by posting more code context and more of the stacktrace. The line you mention doesn't have an opportunity for a NPE, so there must be something different.

Comment: This part : TemplateHandlerRegistryUtil.getTemplateHandler(JournalArticle.class.getName()) return null.

Comment: In the function JournalUtil : public static String transform(ThemeDisplay themeDisplay, Map<String, String> tokens, String viewMode, String languageId, Document document, PortletRequestModel portletRequestModel, String script, String langType, boolean propagateException) throws Exception {
    }

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.liferay.journal.util.impl.JournalUtil.transform(JournalUtil.java:389)

Comment: Please edit your question with that a additional information. It can be formatted there and well be easier to read by far.